# I am using Nelmio_cors but I get a 500 error for POST requests even though I get a CORS-enabled response for GET requests

Tags: symfony, nelmiocorsbundle

I have an API in Symfony 4 using NelmioCorsBundle. I have a Vue.js application that request that same API. I use google chrome as browser.

When I send a GET request There is no problem but when I send a POST I get the following response.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://my_api_domain/api/resource/custom-update' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

I understand it tell me that I need to set 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in my response headers. But for what I understand NelmioCorsBundle should be injecting it automatically.

The bundle is decared in bundle.php

```
return [
  ...
  Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
  ...
];
```

Here is my settings for NelmioCorsBundle

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

- I have already read the documentation for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).
- I do not want a hack to make it work on Chrome or Firefox.
- I have tried to inject manually the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' in my response

Nothing worked.

What did I miss ?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: I get a code 500 for this request. All POST requests seems to return code 500 and all GET requests seems to return code 200 and work as expected.

Comment: OK yeah then the 500 error is the problem you need to fix. You don’t have a CORS problem — if you fix the cause of the 500 error, you’re likely going to find that your existing CORS configuration is already working as expected. To troubleshoot the cause of the 500 error, you need to look at the server logs for the `https://my_api_domain/api/resource/custom-update` server and find what messages the server is logging there which indicate what internal server failure is triggering the server to respond with that 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

may be nonsense but have you formatted the .yml well?
in the sense that to work properly the .yml files must be formatted as follows:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

Otherwise try to add `forced_allow_origin_value` like this:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        forced_allow_origin_value: ['*']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': ~
```

Comment: I don't think i have a format problem. I tried the to add **forced_allow_origin_value** as you suggested but it look like  **forced_allow_origin_value** require a scarlar value. So I tried __forced_allow_origin_value='*'__ but it didnt work as well.

Comment: @Pangebo if the formatting of the code is identical to the one you posted it is wrong and .yml will not work well... in particular `defaults:` and `paths:` must not be on the same vertical line as `nelmio_cors:`

Comment: My bad, I didn't realise I made a copy/paste mistake on my first message. I can assure you that my .yml file respect the indentation. I will correct my first message. Sorry for giving you bad informations